# how to call and use function Recursivity in matlab

Tags: matlab, newtons-method

I have an exercise with newton way calculate `y(x+1)=y(x)-f(x)/f'(x)` in this function I need y(x) and for this I use function Recursivity for y(1) & y(2) it's working because  y(1)  has formula `y(1)=R*T/p` ,for save y(x) I use `zeros()`to use  when calculate y(x+1) but for x>2 I get the same answer,what am I missing??what can I use instead of zeros() for save and access to newt(x-1)

```
function y= newt(x)
%define beta,gamma,delta,....there
y(1)=R*T/p;
answ=zeros(1,20);
z=0;
if  x==1
   f=(R*T*y(1)^3)+(beta*y(1)^2)+(gamma*y(1))+delta-(p*y(1)^4);          
   f1=(3*y(1)^2*R*T)+(2*y(1)*beta)+gamma+(4*p*y(1)^3);          
   answ(1) = y(1);
    fprintf('n=1 v=%f\n',y(1));    
else
    y=newt(x-1);
    f=(R*T*y^3)+(beta*y^2)+(gamma*y)+delta-(p*y^4);
    f1=(3*y^2*R*T)+(2*y*delta)+gamma+(4*p*y^3);
    z=y-f/f1
    answ(1,2:x)=z;
end
  answ(1) = y(1);
   answ(1,2:x)=z;
```

Comment: You can define persistent variables and values of those values retained in memory between calls to the function.

Comment: @User1551892 I would not recommend this way of doing it, as it tends to create a mess. Better to use normal arguments. Anyway about the question; I believe Newtons method is incorrectly implemented. The variable `x` need to be iterativly updated based on the result from the last iteration. Try to use function handles as well as input to the function. This would allow to use a single MATLAB function to calculate zeros for most continous functions.

Comment: @patrik you mean I define an other function??can you show me in code??

Comment: @isan this is homework so I do not want to say to much but what I mean is that you can create a generic equation solver function that takes a function handle as argument `f = @(x) x.^2 - 1; y = newt(@f, x);`. If you want you can include the derivative as another input or otherwise you can make matlab handle this. It is up to you but including derivative is likely easier `f = @(x) x.^2 - 1; fp = @(x) 2*x; y = newt(@f, @fp, x);` . I do not want to give you a correct solution of newtons method since it would be to help you cheat. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according  to @patrik guidance,I find my answer

```
f=@(v)p*v^4-R*T*v^3-beta*v^2-gamma*v-delta;
f1=@(v)4*p*v^3-3*R*T*v^2-2*beta*v-gamma;
```